# How to prevent Nutch / Solr from indexing menus or other html content?

Tags: html, indexing, solr, nutch

I've been working with Solr and Nutch to crawl and index all content from my intranet website (html, pdf, doc, etc). Finally got everything to work (if anybody is having trouble with the crawler see my other question or msg me for help), now the issue I encounter is that ALL HTML content is being indexed, including navigation menus. I'd like to exclude content like this, footers, etc to keep the search results clean and relevant.

Does anybody know how to exclude certain parts of an html page from being indexed? My research lead me to the article below, which includes applying a patch https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-585

How do I apply this patch to my Nutch? Environment: Windows Server 2012 r2, java version "1.8.0_171", solr-7.3.0., nutch 1.8.
Does anybody know of another alternative? Thanks, all help is appreciated.